# Worksheet Activate Infinite Loop

Tags: excel, vba

VBA newbie here.  I searched the responses, but I couldn't find anything useful.  I have a chart in an Excel tab.  I want the Y axis of the chart to dynamically update based on parameters I pass in, so I wrote a simple macro to do so in a VBA module (I have a series with zeros after a certain date in the chart, so I can't just let Excel pick an automatic axis).   The macro works fine when I call it manually (e.g., through a button), but I want it to be invoked every time the user selects the "Fill Strategy" or "Report" tabs.  I'm using the Worksheet_Activate code (see below), but I get stuck in an infinite loop due to the "Sheets("Fill Strategy").Select" and "Sheets("Report").Select" potions of the "UpdateChartAxes" macro (which essentially calls my Worksheet_Activate code again and again).  How do I fix this issue?  Is there a way to redesign the "UpdateChartAxes" code so that it doesn't need the select statements?  Any help would be appreciated.

**Code in the "Fill Strategy" and "Report" tab modules:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Call UpdateChartAxes
End Sub
```

**Code in an open module:**

```
Public Sub UpdateChartAxes()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Call ShowSheets

'WorkforceReportChart
    Dim WorkforceReportChartMin As Long
    Dim WorkforceReportChartMax As Long
    Sheets("Chart Data").Select
    WorkforceReportChartMin = WorksheetFunction.min(Range("ReportGraphDataRangeExcludingHistoricSeries")) * 0.95
    WorkforceReportChartMax = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("ReportGraphDataRangeExcludingHistoricSeries")) * 1.05
    Sheets("Report").Select
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("WorkforceReportChart").Chart
        With .Axes(xlValue)
            .MinimumScale = WorkforceReportChartMin
            .MaximumScale = WorkforceReportChartMax
        End With
    End With

'FillStrategyChart
    Dim FillStrategyChartMin As Long
    Dim FillStrategyChartMax As Long
    Sheets("Chart Data").Select
    FillStrategyChartMin = WorksheetFunction.min(Range("FillStrategyGraphDataRangeExcludingHistoricSeries")) * 0.95
    FillStrategyChartMax = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("FillStrategyGraphDataRangeExcludingHistoricSeries")) * 1.05
    Sheets("Fill Strategy").Select
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("FillStrategyChart").Chart
        With .Axes(xlValue)
            .MinimumScale = FillStrategyChartMin
            .MaximumScale = FillStrategyChartMax
        End With
    End With

Call HideSheets
End Sub
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `*.Select .. Active<obj>..` in macros.  Especially not ones that interact with the Activate events.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid writing a macro to do this - just base your chart on dynamic named ranges. See this link for more info: http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/DynamicRanges.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
Public Sub UpdateChartAxes()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Call ShowSheets
Dim curWs as Worksheet

'WorkforceReportChart
    Dim WorkforceReportChartMin As Long
    Dim WorkforceReportChartMax As Long
    'Sheets("Chart Data").Select
    Set curWs = Sheets("Chart Data")
    WorkforceReportChartMin = WorksheetFunction.min(Range(curWs.Name & "!ReportGraphDataRangeExcludingHistoricSeries")) * 0.95
    WorkforceReportChartMax = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(curWs.Name & "!ReportGraphDataRangeExcludingHistoricSeries")) * 1.05
    'Sheets("Report").Select
    Set curWs = Sheets("Report")
    With curWs.ChartObjects("WorkforceReportChart").Chart
        With .Axes(xlValue)
            .MinimumScale = WorkforceReportChartMin
            .MaximumScale = WorkforceReportChartMax
        End With
    End With

'FillStrategyChart
    Dim FillStrategyChartMin As Long
    Dim FillStrategyChartMax As Long
    'Sheets("Chart Data").Select
    Set curWs = Sheets("Chart Data")
    FillStrategyChartMin = WorksheetFunction.min(Range(curWs.Name & "!FillStrategyGraphDataRangeExcludingHistoricSeries")) * 0.95
    FillStrategyChartMax = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(curWs.Name & "!FillStrategyGraphDataRangeExcludingHistoricSeries")) * 1.05
    'Sheets("Fill Strategy").Select
    Set Sheets("Fill Strategy")
    With curWs.ChartObjects("FillStrategyChart").Chart
        With .Axes(xlValue)
            .MinimumScale = FillStrategyChartMin
            .MaximumScale = FillStrategyChartMax
        End With
    End With

Call HideSheets
End Sub
```